# Irreducibility of regular representation

Tags: representation-theory, ideals

Okay, so this might be a very dumb question, but I recently proved that for an associative algebra $A$, any representation $V$ of $A$ is irreducible iff every $v \in V$ is a cyclic vector, i.e $Av$  = $V$. Won't this make the regular representation of $A$ irreducible?

Comment: What proof did you have in mind? For example, take $A = k[X]$ and the element $v=X^2\in A$. This is not cyclic, of course.

Comment: I was just thinking generally. For any element $a \in A$, $Aa = A$, but seems to me that this is wrong, seeing your counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

The cyclic vectors in the regular representation are the units of the algebra, so every non-zero element of an algebra is a cyclic vector if and only if the algebra is a field.  The regular representation of a field is indeed irreducible.